# Android onCreateOptionsMenu is not called

Tags: android

I am debugging on a Nexus, Android version 5.0

My Min SDK is 11, target SDK is 21.

I have the following XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="@string/settings_label"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

And in my launcher activity I have this Java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i("Inside onCreateOptionsMenu", "True");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);
    return true;
}
```

However that Log line never makes it into LogCat, and my menu is never displayed.

My desired effect is to have an action bar with the 3 vertical dots which when clicked by the user will show my menu item.

Comment: Are you doing it inside an Activity or Fragment? If it's a fragment, call `setHasOptionMenu(true)`

Comment: Quote from my post: And in my launcher activity

Comment: are you using actionbarsherlock? getSupportMenuInflater() should be used in that case.

Comment: I am using the code posted. Standard menu

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the tutorial from several different providers as follows which are recommended by SO

[Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)
[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)
[AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

All of them have great examples and source code to help you out